# ViewPager don't work corectry with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have problem in my `ViewPager` in fragment.
When I open fragment from navigation view, my 'ListView' works only in I have one tab.
When I put 2 or more tabs, wrong list view appears only in second tab.

Here is my fragment `ViewPager`:

```
public class JournaFragment extends Fragment{

private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

JournalDate journalDate;
ArrayList<JournalDate> monthArray ;
JournalSwipeAdapter monthAdapter;

public JournaFragment(){}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, null);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    journalDate = new JournalDate();
    monthArray = journalDate.getMounthForTable();
    monthAdapter = new JournalSwipeAdapter(ParentActivity.getContext(),monthArray);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(monthAdapter);



    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    //System.out.println(" CurrentItem :" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    monthAdapter.getLessonsForJournal(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

    monthAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return v;
}




@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

and Adapter extend PagerAdapter:

```
public class JournalSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<JournalDate> arrayList;

ProgressBar pg;
TextView title;
TextView noJournal;
TextView indexPage;

ListView dayListView;
ArrayList<JournalFragmentDayItem> dayItemArrayList;
JournalFragmentDayItem dayItem;
JournalFragmentDayAdapter dayAdapter;

public JournalSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<JournalDate> arrayList) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (arrayList == null) {
        return 0;

    } else
        return arrayList.size();

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return o == view;
}


public JournalDate getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (arrayList.get(position).calendar) {
        case (0):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Январь";
            break;
        case (1):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Февраль";
            break;
        case (2):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Март";
            break;
        case (3):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Апрель";
            break;
        case (4):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Май";
            break;
        case (5):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Июнь";
            break;
        case (6):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Июль";
            break;
        case (7):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Август";
            break;
        case (8):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Сентябрь";
            break;
        case (9):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Октябрь";
            break;
        case (10):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Ноябрь";
            break;
        case (11):
            arrayList.get(position).month = "Декабрь";
            break;
    }
    return arrayList.get(position).month;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Inflate a new layout from our resources
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jourlan_swipe_layout, container, false);
    // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
    container.addView(view);

    // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    pg = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    dayListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_journal_swipe_list);
    noJournal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_journal_swipe_nojournal);
    indexPage = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    view.setTag("myView"+position);
    noJournal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Return the View
    return view;
}


public void getLessonsForJournal(final int position) {
    HtmlRequest htmlRequest;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
   // System.out.println(" Position: "+ position);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("studentId", "5");
    params.put("year", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).year));
    params.put("mounth", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).calendar + 1));

    htmlRequest = new HtmlRequest(Request.Method.POST, Links.getJournalLessons, params, "UTF-8",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                   // System.out.println(" " +response);
                    if (response.equals("false")) {
                       // System.out.println("Failed Lessons ");

                    } else {

                        arrayList.get(position).responseForLessons = response;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                        dayItem = new JournalFragmentDayItem();
                        dayItemArrayList = dayItem.getDayArray(arrayList.get(position).responseForLessons);
                        dayAdapter = new JournalFragmentDayAdapter(ParentActivity.getContext(), dayItemArrayList);
                        dayListView.setAdapter(dayAdapter);

                        pg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        dayListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("eror", error.getMessage() + "");
                    Toast.makeText(ParentActivity.getContext(), "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    htmlRequest.setTag("TAG");
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ParentActivity.getContext());
    requestQueue.add(htmlRequest);


}


/**
 * Destroy the item from the ViewPager. In our case this is simply
 * removing the View.
 */
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that inside `ViewPagerAdapter` you are using the same elements for every page (`ListView`, etc...). This way only the last instantiated page is shown.

Try not reusing them inside the function `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` and create them inside the method.

**EDIT**

Guidelines to help you understand what changes should be made:

Your updated class fields:

```
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<JournalDate> arrayList;

ArrayList<JournalFragmentDayItem> dayItemArrayList;
JournalFragmentDayItem dayItem;
JournalFragmentDayAdapter dayAdapter;
```

Updated method `public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)`:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Inflate a new layout from our resources
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_jourlan_swipe_layout, container, false);
    // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
    container.addView(view);

    // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ListView dayListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_journal_swipe_list);
    TextView noJournal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_journal_swipe_nojournal);
    TextView indexPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    view.setTag("myView" + position);
    noJournal.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Return the View
    return view;
}
```

Comment: can you show any example? i realy use pageadapter for first time

Comment: yes. i think it's a good way. i have some bugs with this solution. need time to resolve it

Comment: i think it work only for first tab, and i no apear. for see what in the first tab i need to enter in thee tab and back to first. any ideas ?

Comment: and the problem is, when i start fragment in Object instantiateItem always show 2 position of 0 and 1. maybe the better way do JSON only on visible element. and create listview. but don't see way to move

Comment: Can you only help me. this problem killing me